Difference between "backpedal" and "change your tune"
Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'backpedal' and 'change your tune'? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

backpedal: to change an opinion that you had expressed before, or do something different from what you had said you would do
change your tune: to change your opinion completely, especially because you know it will bring you an advantage


Backpedaling involves an attempt to unsay, either completely or merely to some degree, what has been previously said, to "walk it back". It is a form of damage control. The speaker or their representatives might say something along the lines that what was said previously was misunderstood in some way, and that the received impression was not at all what was intended.
Changing one's tune is to take a position that differs rather sharply from one previously held, but it is not necessarily an attempt to walk the previous position back.  It might be alleged that new conditions require a change of position. Or the person might just say whatever they feel needs to be said at any given moment, relying upon the limited memory and easy manipulability of the people they need to reach.
Both terms are used somewhat pejoratively, applied to someone else.

Also, backpedal can mean not entirely reverse an earlier statement but reduce its extent, intensity, etc. Thus, if one replaced an earlier statement of I’m the single best in the world by the less immodest I’m among the very best, we could call that backpedaling.

@PaulTanenbaum - and it's backpedalling in the BritZone (TM)

Which only demonstrates, @MichaelHarvey, what a strange and wondrous place is Ye Olde BZ.

I've backpedaled by adding a qualification :-)
